# esc_url on WordPress ACF oEmbed

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com) WordPress plugin to create an oEmbed field. The field accepts a URL from Vimeo and outputs an iframe on the front end.

I usually escape urls and attributes within my theme like so:

```
<a href="<?= esc_url( get_field('link') ); ?>" title="<?= esc_attr( get_field('title') ); ?>">
```

When I try and escape the oEmbed, nothing shows up:

```
<?= esc_url( get_field('video') ); ?>
```

If I test XSS with the following script, the ACF field completely breaks with a JS error.

```
<script>alert('hello')</script>
```

Do I need to escape this field? I assume that WordPress takes care of the escaping through the oEmbed function?

Comment: To clarify, when you remove the esc_url() function, does the URL output correctly?

Comment: Yes, the field spits out an iframe and correctly shows the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/oembed/):

> The oEmbed field will return a string containing the embed HTML.

Even if the input is of type URL, when getting the value, ACF transforms it to a full HTML embed code. In conclusion, it is wrong to call `esc_url` on this HTML, you just have to use `the_field('video')` or `echo get_field('video')`.

As for ACF accepting invalid (non-URL) data in oEmbed type inputs, you can write a custom validator to raise an error, if needed by implementing a filter: [acf/validate_value](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-validate_value/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the_field() instead of get_field()?

```
<?= esc_url( the_field('video') ); ?>
```

The oEmbed actually returns more than just a url so that could be the issue as well.  I haven't worked with esc_url() much in the past but it could be breaking because whatever is getting passed through is not only a url.

As stated here, https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/oembed/, "The oEmbed field will return a string containing the embed HTML".

Comment: ! Function `the_field` echoes the values, not returns them, so `esc_url( the_field('video') )` is the same as `the_field('video'); echo NULL;`